# Play a .g64 file extension

Tags: file-formats, windows

A legal friend of mine received a file from a colleague with a .g64 file extension that she needs to view.  My searching indicates that the .64 file extension is some form of proprietary security video format but I can't determine the exact software.

I checked VLC but it doesn't look like there is any native support for it, and I couldn't find any addon codecs for it.  Other references to download player software for it look like they are probably just click-bait scams.

Any ideas what I can use to play the video?

Comment: Have you tried the portable player: http://downloadcenter1.genetec.com/products/SecurityCenter/5.1/SR3/Tools/PortableArchivePlayer/PortableArchivePlayer.exe ?

Comment: It's been a while but I was able to find a player for it.  It's been long enough that I just don't remember exactly what it was but genetec sounds very familiar.  Thanks for the reply ;-)

Answer (score 0):

.g64 is the extension of the proprietary video format from Genetec, a provider of IP video surveillance. Even 5 years after your question I have not found any library to open them or player to read them other than the official player. Not sure where to find it, part of their doc is behind a login wall. You might try http://downloadcenter.genetec.com/products/SecurityCenter/GenetecVideoPlayer/GenetecVideoPlayer.exe